# How to work with refresh token in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, okhttp

I need to catch an expired token by sending a refreshToken and in return get new access_token and refresh_token. Below I have laid out the code that I am going to use. It is not written completely, because I do not completely understand everything.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/o/token/")
Call<TokenModel> getToken(
        @Field("username") String username,
        @Field("password") String password,
        @Field("client_id") String clientId,
        @Field("client_secret") String clientSecret,
        @Field("grant_type") String grantType
);
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/o/token/")
Call<TokenModel> getNewToken(
        @Field("refresh_token") String refreshToken,
        @Field("client_id") String clientId,
        @Field("client_secret") String clientSecret,
        @Field("grant_type") String grantType
);

@GET("/api/users/profile")
Call<UserProfile> getProfile();
```

I indicated question marks where I do not specifically understand.
I just didn't quite figure it out with Hader. What should I put there after the comma? All that the server requires from me to receive a new token? (In my case, it is String refreshToken, String clientId, String clientSecret, String grantType) or not?

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .addInterceptor(new AccessTokenInterceptor(preferences))


            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @NotNull
                @Override
                public Response intercept(@NotNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request original = chain.request();
                    Request request = original.newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization", ?)
                            .method(original.method(), original.body())
                            .build();

                    Response response =  chain.proceed(request);
                    Log.d("MyApp", "Code : "+response.code());
                    if (response.code() == 401){
                        ?
                        return response;
                    }
                    return response;
                }
            })
            .build();
```